# Llenar una DropDownList dependiendo de los datos con los que se carga un Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un proyecto en donde listo una serie de productos, estos tienen especificaciones de tamaño por separados y cada uno es distinto, entonces yo tengo un repeater que lleno desde una consulta de sql, dentro de el hay una DropDownList la cual va a listar los tamaños de cada producto, yo necesitaría enviar un campo que trae la tabla que llena el repeater hacia el ItemDataBound para poder recuperar con otra consulta a la base de datos el producto con sus respectivos tamaños. Por si no me doy a entender dejo el aspx aqui. Intente enviar datos a través de unos atributo de la etiqueta sin saber si era correcto o no con <%# Eval("DATO")%>, pero me daba error al ejecutar la app.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repProductos" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repProductos_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="contenedorProducto">
                    <div></div>
                    <div class="imagenProducto">
                        <img src="img/<%# Eval("imagen")%>.jpg" width="265" height="255"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="separacion"></div>
                    <div class="especificacionProducto">
                        <h2 id="header"><%# Eval("nombreProducto")%></h2>
                        <div class="TamanioYCantidad">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTalles" CssClass="ddlTalles" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCantidad" CssClass="txtCantidad" TextMode="Number" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Debe ingresar un numero entre 0 y 99" CssClass="lblErrorCantidad" ControlToValidate="txtCantidad" ForeColor="#8a2be2" MaximumValue="99" MinimumValue="0" Font-Size="10px"></asp:RangeValidator>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAgregarCarrito1" CssClass="btnAgregarCarrito" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" Text="Agregar al carrito"/>
                    </div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui una solucion, la dejo detallada por si algun dia alguien la necesita.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repProductos" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repProductos_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="contenedorRemeras">
                        <div></div>
                        <div class="imagenProducto">
                            <img src="img/<%# Eval("imagen")%>.jpg" width="265" height="255" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="separacion"></div>
                        <div class="especificacionProducto">
                            <h2 id="header"><%# Eval("nombreProducto")%></h2>
                            
                            <!--Agregue un HiddenField para almacenar la variable con la cual recuperaba los distintos talles de cada producto-->
                            <asp:HiddenField id="hfIdTallesProducto" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("idGrupoTalles")%>'/>

                            <div class="TalleYCantidad">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTalles" CssClass="ddlTalles" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCantidad" CssClass="txtCantidad" TextMode="Number" runat="server">0</asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Debe ingresar un numero entre 0 y 99" CssClass="lblErrorCantidad" ControlToValidate="txtCantidad" ForeColor="#8a2be2" MaximumValue="99" MinimumValue="0" Font-Size="10px"></asp:RangeValidator>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAgregarCarrito1" CssClass="btnAgregarCarrito" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" Text="Agregar al carrito" />
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Ademas en el ItemDataBound cree el siguiente codigo

```
protected void repProductos_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            DropDownList ddlTalles = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlTalles");
            string hfIdTalle = ((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfIdTallesProducto")).Value;

            DataTable dtTalles = ddlCargarTalles(hfIdTalle);

            ddlTalles.DataSource = dtTalles;
            ddlTalles.DataValueField = "talle";
            ddlTalles.DataTextField = "talle";
            ddlTalles.DataBind();    
        }
        
    }
```

Y cree una funcion que recuperaba la tabla con los talles

```
public DataTable ddlCargarTalles(String idTalle)
    {
        Talles recTalles = new Talles();

        DataTable talles = recTalles.RecuperaLosTallesSegunIdGrupoTalle(idTalle);
       
        return talles;
    }
```